# creating a chainable method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been trying to create my own chainable method in laravel' eloquent but I'm missing something and not sure what. This may sound a little bit nuts but have a look at my function below to get a better idea of what I'm trying to say.

```
class Post extends Eloquent{
    public static function custom_wh($data){
        return static::where_in('categories_id', $data, 'AND');
    }
}

//this works fine
$posts = Post::custom_wh(array(1, 2, 3))->get();

//but this says custom_wh is not defined in the query class
$posts = Post::where_in('tags', array(2, 3, 4), 'AND')->custom_wh(array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

if I understand correctly then my method is not eligible to chain after another method? So I guess my question is how can I create a chainable method in my model?

P.S I have looked into the laravel's query builder class where I have seen that the chainable methods returns the instance of that object but I couldn't find a way to return the object other than the way I've done in the code above. Any kind of suggestion or advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that in Laravel with the "query scopes". You can find the doc [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes).

You just have to write a function with the prefix `scope` and you will be able to chain this method like the other query builder ones :

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeWhereCategories($query, $categories)
    {
        return $query->whereIn('categories_id', $categories, 'AND');
    }

}

$posts = Post::whereCategories([1, 2, 3])->get();
$posts = Post::orderBy('date')->whereCategories([1, 2, 3])->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: Love this feature and been using it already :D I know this didn't exist back when I posted my question but I'm selecting this as the correct answer for other googlers like me. thanks.

Comment: @Alexandre Butynski for what 3rd param is used for ? `('categories_id', $categories, 'AND');`

Comment: @DaniyalNasir, I don't know ! It's just a copy past from initial question. Anyway, it seems pretty useless because it is the default value for this param...

Comment: @AlexandreButynski Oh alright but it does take where operator as 3rd parameter right ? *I'm new to Laravel*

Answer (score 12):

OK... This may warp your brain a bit but stick with me. The actual method defined is _where(). So how does both Post::where and $post->where end up calling the _where() method? The answer is 'magic'. :D

PHP has these things called 'magic methods' which enable some very dynamic behaviour. In this case Laravel is using __callStatic() and __call() to handle calls to undefined methods. This enabled the same method to be called statically and non-statically.

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    // Create a new instance of the called class, in this case it is Post
    $model = get_called_class();

    // Call the requested method on the newly created object
    return call_user_func_array(array(new $model, $method), $parameters);
}
```

So basically Post::where() is just shorthand for $post = new Post; $post->where()

From here the request goes to __call() in which there is an array of underscored method names. If the requested method is in the list of underscored names, then $this->_method() is called and returned.

But this is still not the whole story. Drew is correct in that 'where_in' returns a Query object. Most of the ORM chaining methods you are familiar with are actually part of the ORM Query object. Here is the whole process.

- Post::where( ... )
- Post::__callStatic( 'where', ... )
- $post->__call( 'where', ... )
- $query->_call( 'where', ... )
- $query->_where( ... )

The class you want to extend is the Query that is used by Model. There is no way add another method name to the list of underscored methods defined in __call(). You will have to copy __call() in it's entirety into your Query definition in order to enable your new method to have that behaviour.

I have accomplished this in my projects be pointing Eloquent ( the alias for the Laravel model ) to my extended version, enabling all my models to use the extended Query methods.

```
// application/libraries/mylib/query.php
namespace MyLib;

class Model extends \Laravel\Model {

    // Tell \MyLib\Model to use \MyLib\Query instead of Laravels Query
    protected function query()
    { 
        return new \MyLib\Query($this);
    } 

}

// application/libraries/mylib/query.php
namespace MyLib;

class Query extends \Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query {

    function _my_method() { ... }

    function __call() { ... }
}

// application/config/application.php
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Eloquent' => 'MyLib\\Model',
    ...
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php#L734
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/eloquent/query.php#L274

Comment: that explains a lot. to be honest I haven't studied much about OO in php and I started using frameworks cause I thought I'd learn OO as I go along so yeah this is quite much to have a grip on but Lemme a shot at it using your technic. I'll keep you posted if I have any further questions along the way. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i am accurate but this is what i came up with quick...

Post::where_in() is not returning an Eloquent model it is returning object of type Query.

For how simply you have written your custom function I would just avoid the function

```
$posts = Post::where_in('tags', array(2, 3, 4))->where_in('categories_ids', array(1,2,3))->get();
```

from the top of my head

you could try something like

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    public static function custom_wh($data=array()) {
        return static::where_in('categories_id', $data);
        // return type of query not eloquent
    }
}

$posts = Post::custom_wh(array(1,2,3))->where_in('tags', array(2, 3, 4))->get();
```

unless you wanted to alter the query class

Comment: well, that's what I did and it works but the problem is the custom_wh function is not chainable so suppose I have a huge query that needs to do several join, where clauses so I want to wrap them in seperate functions and chain them when needed, then the problem appears. One more reason that I'm trying to put them in a function is cause the ORM shouldn't be my model right? and I'm also trying to keep my code "DRY".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'self' instead of 'static'? As far as I know, if you use self and the attribute/method and you subclass and the method that you are referring to is does not override the main class attribute/method, it will return, in this case the, the method 'where_in' of the Query class. And then you will be able to chain you custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can extend eloquent builder easily and just run :

```
$posts = Post::custom_wh(array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

You have instructions at my answer here : [Laravel Custom Model Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658479/laravel-custom-model-methods/51720169)

also, don't use scopes for that except you now exactly what are you doing, this is also clarified at my answer.