# Creating a chainable method in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've tried to update [this excellent solution of Collin James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15182765/1709022) to work in **Laravel 4**.

Until know without luck. This is what I came up with:

**/app/libraries/Model.php** (i've registered the libraries directory using composer)

```
namespace Elegant;

class Model extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    function __construct() 
    {
        echo 'Show me if the Model exension works<br />';
    }

    protected function query()
    {
        echo 'Show me if the query function gets called<br />';
        return new \Elegant\Query($this);
    }
}
```

**/app/libraries/Query.php** (i've registered the libraries directory using composer)

```
namespace Elegant;

class Query extends \Illuminate\Database\Query {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        echo 'Show me if the Query exension works<br />';
    }

    public function byArray($column, $value) 
    {
        if (is_array($value))
            return $this->whereIn($column, $value);
        else
            return $this->where($column, '=', $value);
    }

    public function __call()
    {
    }
}
```

**/app/config/app.php**

```
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Eloquent'        => 'Elegant\Model',
    ...
)
```

The only thing that works is:

- "Show me if the Model exension works".

The other "markers" don't work:

- query() doesn't get called at all
- Eloquent/Query is used, instead of looking at Elegant/Query first

Comment: None of this is probably necessary, can you instead tell us what you want to do (as it's probably possibly without overwriting the method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is QueryScopes what you mean? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes
You can add custom scopes for the query. You can also add extra parameters, but the $query is always added (and is the current query)
Probably something like:

```
public function scopeByArray($query, $column, $value)
{
    if (is_array($value))
        return $query->whereIn($column, $value);
    else
        return $query->where($column, '=', $value);
}
```

And then just `User::byArray($column, $value)->orderBy(..)`

And you can just extend Eloquent and add functions there (`class BaseModel extends Eloquent`)

Comment: Would it also be possible to set the $hidden and $visible properties in this way?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917051/laravel-eloquent-eager-loaded-hidden-visible-properties