# Laravel4: call static method from instantiated class object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Normally Eloquent model is used as following:

```
class Article extends Eloquent
{
 // Eloquent Article implementation
}

class MyController extends BaseController
{
 public function getIndex()
 {
  $articles = Article::all(); // call static method

  return View::make('articles.index')->with('articles', $articles);
 }
}
```

But when restructing use Dependency Injection, it looks like that:

```
interface IArticleRepository
{
 public function all();
}

class EloquentArticleRepository implements IArticleRepository
{
 public function __construct(Eloquent $article)
 {
  $this->article = $article;
 }

 public function all()
 {
  return $this->article->all(); // call instance method
 }
}
```

So why we can call the static method Article::all() in form of instance method $this->article->all()?

P/S: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Change `public function all()` to `static public function all()`

Answer (score 2):

**Good question.**

Laravel utilize the `Facade design pattern`. when you call `Article::all()`, a lot of things happened behind the screen. First, PHP try to call the static method if it fails php immediately call a magic method `_callStatic`. then Laravel cleverly capture the `static call` and create instance of  the original class.

From Laravel doc:

`Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's IoC container. Laravel ships with many facades, and you have probably been using them without even knowing it!`

**More info:**

http://laravel.com/docs/facades

http://usman.it/laravel-4-uses-static-not-true/

Comment: Thanks for answer me. In my opinion, Facade references to Laravel core class, not user created Eloquent models. I skimmed at Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php (which is Eloquent alias) and saw that all() is defined here as static method. Am I wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070809/creating-a-chainable-method-in-laravel/15182765#15182765